# When creating a table inside a div. Text "undefined" shows up for no reason

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have this table I create in a div. On a button click a table is being created inside a div. This is the html code I use to create an empty div, when the page is being opened:

```
<div id="historyTableDiv">    
</div>
```

This is the Javascript code I execute when a button is clicked to create the table inside the div:

```
function createTable()
{
    var text = 'ID: TEST<br>';
    var thead = '<table><thead><tr><td>#</td><td>Name</td></tr></thead><tbody>';
    var tbody = '<tr>';
    tbody += '<td>Test ID</td>';        
    tbody += '<td>Test Name</td>';
    var tfooter = '</tr></tbody></table>';
    document.getElementById('historyTableDiv').innerHTML = text + thead + tbody + tfooter;
}
```

The table is created just fine. The only problem is that the text `"undefined"` is showing up between the text `"ID: TEST"` and the table. I have absolutely no idea where this coming from.

Extra info:
I have 6 divs on my page. With all different id's. I use the `createTable()` function. To show the same table in different divs and above every table the text "undefined" shows up.

When I inspect the element I see that the nodeValue attribute of this div has the value "undefined" when I change this text to "test" the text "test" shows up instead of undefined.

Comment: you mean that everything you want is displayed, but with also an undefined  ? nothing missing ?

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/emzOZN

Comment: try putting <br/> instead of <br> , it may explain why

Comment: It looks fine here ..

Comment: Did you try in another browser ?

Comment: working fine check at http://jsfiddle.net/skweL11q/

Comment: No errors here, working fine.

Comment: yes everything is being displayed fine and nothing is missing adn yes I tried it in different browsers @sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by editing the value of the first node of the div after passing content to the innerHTML attribute. I still have no idea what is causing this.

```
document.getElementById('historyTableDiv').innerHTML = text + thead + tbody + tfooter;
document.getElementById('historyTableDiv').childNodes[0].nodeValue = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the above code, may be the problem is in some other part. Can you share your full html and js code?

The following code works fine for me.

```html
   <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <p><button onclick="createTable()">Create Table</button></p>
            <div id="historyTableDiv">
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function createTable() {
                    var text = 'ID: TEST<br>';
                    var thead = '<table><thead><tr><td>#</td><td>Name</td></tr></thead><tbody>';
                    var tbody = '<tr>';
                    tbody += '<td>Test ID</td>';        
                    tbody += '<td>Test Name</td>';
                    var tfooter = '</tr></tbody></table>';
                    document.getElementById('historyTableDiv').innerHTML = text + thead + tbody + tfooter;
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There is no other code, where I change the innerHTML attribute of a div.